# Dajaxice calls itself and causes an error

Tags: django, dajaxice

Tried to get on with Dajaxice, set simple project and then got this:

```
No module named 'Dajaxice'
```

Traceback highlights 2 cases below:

```
C:\study\django\dajax_geton\dajax_geton\urls.py in <module>
from dajaxice.core import dajaxice_autodiscover, dajaxice_config

C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\dajaxice\core\__init__.py in <module>
from Dajaxice import Dajaxice, dajaxice_autodiscover
```

Well, I feel kind a strange when the error could been caused by some bug in Dajaxice module.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from dajaxice.core import dajaxice_autodiscover, dajaxice_config
dajaxice_autodiscover()
from views import view_index

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'index/$', view_index),
url(dajaxice_config.dajaxice_url, include('dajaxice.urls')),
)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

chenges in **settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'dajaxice',)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
'dajaxice.finders.DajaxiceFinder',)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.core.context_processors.debug',
'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
'django.core.context_processors.media',
'django.core.context_processors.static',
'django.core.context_processors.request',
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages')
```

Maybe I'm doing something stupid, which causes the error?
Or, maybe, provide me some link with simple working project with dajaxice? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dajaxice does not yet support Python 3.

There is a pull request [#112](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajaxice/pull/112) with a patch that fixes the `ImportError`. However, there may be other issues running Dajaxice with Python 3, so I would use Python 2.7 for now.